# C# reading Excel missing column

Tags: c#, excel

I have excel (.xls) file with 4 column and all columns are "general" and with no header.
Column A and B contains some text, column C contains numbers, column D contains text.
When I read data (code below) reader can see only 3 columns (A,B,C), reader dose not see (recognize) column D (picture below).
I have added IMEX=1 in connection string, I have changed registry - TypeGuessRows set it to 0 (image below), but all of this did not help me - still have same problem.
Does anyone know why after column that contains numbers JET dose not see txt column?

```
string sourceFileServer = @"C:\TEST\Excel1.xls";
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sourceFileServer + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";"))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$];", connection);
                connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                int _row = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    _row++;
                    try
                    {
                        string _v0 = ((string)reader[0]).Trim();
                        string _v1 = ((string)reader[1]).Trim();
                        string _v2 = reader[2].ToString().Trim();
                        string _v3 = ((string)reader[3]).Trim();
                        MessageBox.Show(_v0 + "|" + _v1 + "|" + _v2 + "|" + _v3 + "|");
                    }
                    catch (Exception xcp)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(xcp.Message);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
```

[reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aDvW.jpg)
[registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQp1R.jpg)

Comment: any chance to see sample xls?

Comment: Sorry I can't share original file.

Comment: Your code runs well on my box with xls with 4 columns i.e. it is due to a format of your source file. Try another file.